# How do I write a VB or C# GUI client for DotNetOpenAuth?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, user-interface, dotnetopenauth

I am learning how to use the Google Calendar API, which in turn requires that I learn how to use DotNetOpenAuth to access the Google account.  I made the provided samples work, and have written working code in a Console program to access and manipulate a Calendar.

I now want to write a Windows Form app (in either C# or VB) to do the same thing.  I can't make the OAuth2 process work in the GUI application.  It compiles and runs, but does not work.  Based on what I've seen so far, I have concluded that the GetAuthorization() function is not called.

I've tried starting the process from a button click, from the constructor, and from the form Loader method.  I've tried in both C# and VB.

```
public GoogleCal()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(
                           GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
    provider.ClientIdentifier = "xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    provider.ClientSecret = "yyyyy";

    var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(
                       provider, GetAuthorization);
}

private IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
{
    // Get the auth URL:
    IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] {
                               CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue() });

    state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
    Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

    // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
    Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
    authCodeText = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(
                                                   "Paste code:", "title", "");

    // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
    return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCodeText, state);
}
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's a similar question, but not quite what I was asking.  (On the other hand, it may be as close as I can get...)  The solutions discussed there appear to be .asp-only.  I'm looking for something that is c# or vb only.

Comment: ASP is vb or C# are you not looking for something .net just vb6 ? or maybe winforms or wpf ? there is not enough information to get what you are looking for

Comment: I'm trying to create a Windows Form Application VS 2010.

Comment: "Windows Form app (in either C# or VB)" - sorry I didn't read this

Answer (score 0):

Using the tutorial at whelkaholism.blogspot, I was able to do what I wanted to do.  I took a somewhat different approach (in part to use the more-recent OAuth2).

My C# form program code is below.

```
// Add references:
//      DotNetOpenAuth.dll
//      Google.Apis.dll
//      Google.Apis.Authentication.OAth2.dll
//      Newtonsoft.Json.Net35.dll
// plus, add references for whichever Google App(s) you want
//      Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.dll

// form contains at least the following:
//      button1: Button, start the authentication process
//      authCode: TextBox, to recive the auth code from Google
//      button2: Button, complete the authentication prop
//      textBox2: TextBox, multi-line, to display status message and output

// in addition to the libraries required for any forms program, use:
using System.Diagnostics;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Util;


// methods not related to authentication deleted for space

namespace GoogleCal
{
    public partial class GoogleCal : Form
    {
        private static String NL = Environment.NewLine;
        private static IAuthorizationState state;
        private static NativeApplicationClient provider;
        private static OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient> auth;
        private static CalendarService calService;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // clicked to initiate authentication process

            // provider and state are declared above as private static

            provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
            provider.ClientIdentifier = "<my id>.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            provider.ClientSecret = "<my secret>";

            // next line changes if you want to access something other than Calendar
            state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue() });
            state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
            Uri authUri = provider.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

            Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // clicked after Google code is pasted into TextBox to complete authentication process

            // auth and calService are declared above as private static

            auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);

            // create the service object to use in other methods
            calService = new CalendarService(auth);

            textBox2.AppendText("Ready" + NL);
            textBox2.Update();
        }

        private IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
        {
            // state is declared above as private static
            // authCode is a TextBox on the form
            return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode.Text, state);
        }
    }
}
```